# Unable to compare two Strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, compare

I am trying two compare two strings in JavaScript. But I guess there is some problem while comparing.  It doesn't show the results.

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

    var msg = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    var fld = document.getElementById("prtCnt");
    if(msg == "false") {
        var msg = "This User Name is already taken !!!!";
        fld.className = "bp_invalid";
        //   fld.style.color=green;
        fld.innerHTML=msg;
    }
```

Can any body tell me where the problem is?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you even check the value of `msg`?

Comment: with out if condition it shows me false on web page. But with if it fails.

Comment: You might as well add the following "print" statement to see what value you are receiving in `msg`: `alert(msg);`  Put that before your `if(msg == 'false')...` test, and amend your question with that additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check if there's any space before or after the "false" string that you return from the server.  You can do it easily with this:

```
alert('"' + msg + '"');
```

If there is extra space, you can just do:

```
msg = msg.trim();
```

and then do your if statement

Comment: it worked thanks a lot. But can you tell me why there was whit space in msg While i was just returning a false word via                          out.print("false");

Comment: Are you calling out.print("false"); from a jsp page?  Maybe there's extra space before the starting tag or after the closing tag?

Comment: How can i get rid of Whit spaces . Is there any way instead of using trim() method as IE doesn't support it. Thanks

Comment: Pffious lost half a hour to discover my string had a whitespace somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that there is no white space around the word "false" with something like:

```
if( msg.match(/\s*false\s*/i) )
```