# success callback

Tags: jquery

I'm using an ajax post like so...

```
$(document).on("click",".Resend",function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        timeout: 3000,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(myhtml){
            // If success
            if (myhtml == "success") {
                    alert(myhtml);
            } else {
                    alert("No");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP/HTML that is called back for example is a simple as this...

```
<?php
    echo "success";
?>
```

For some odd reason I am getting the false return alert = No.  Can someone explain to me why this might happen?

Comment: There could be whitespace before or after the string.  Try `$.trim(myhtml) == 'success'`.

Comment: You should `alert(myhtml)` and see exactly what it is, or even better put a breakpoint in the success handler and examine the exact value of the variables.

Comment: This is weird. I did an alert(myhtml) and there was no white spaces yet when I did @Rocket's solutions $.trim(myhtml) it returned true.

Comment: You don't see whitespace in `alert()`...

Comment: no i didnt. I don't know if there was a trailing white space after the word but there was definitely not a white space before. Does jquery add white spaces on callback? This was a simple callback.

Comment: No, I mean it isn't possible to see a trailing space in an alert. You probably have a space after the `?>`.

Comment: @Julana Dang you are right haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the page you're posting to exists, it is possible that the contents of the response includes some white space; therefore, the string comparison would fail.

You can try this:

```
if ($.trim(myhtml) == 'success') {
  alert(myhtml)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here: [Unable to compare two Strings in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543633/unable-to-compare-two-strings-in-javascript/9543709#9543709)

I think you might have the same problem.

Try do something like this in your success callback and see what the response text looks like:

```
alert('"' + myhtml + '"');
```

I'm suspecting there's leading or trailing space in your response.  That might happen if there's space before your php starting or after the closing tag.

Comment: It's weird that white spaces are added to this simple echo.

Comment: Can you post the content in your php file?  I don't think it's from the the echo.

Comment: There was a white space after the ?> :(

Answer (score 0):

A JSON response format would avoid this kind of annoying issues with plain text.